# What is the best way to learn about the EASA regulation structure?

Tags: easa

I want to increase my awareness of EASA regulations and be able to better understand the differences between EASA baseline regs and operator regs.

However, I frequentl get lost on the EASA website trying to navigate the regulations. It seems I always only find the amendments but not the latest base docs. I am interested in, e.g., flight duty regulations, low wx procedures. What is the best way to get to grips with EASA?

Comment: It is funny that almost a year later, no one even commented on this.